# Помогите оптимизировать код JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Есть JavaScript который управляет менюшкой (полностью рабочий). Его задача выдвигать задвигать меню за край вьюпорта, при выдвижении определять высоту хедера и размещать менюшку прямо под ним, изменять ширину вьюпорта и соответственно варьировать ширину меню, при скролле вниз перемещать менюшку в топ и возвращать под хедер при возврате в топ страницы. 
Код написан с 0 моими кривыми, неопытными руками. Не прошу делать за меня, просто подскажите как можно эту кучу повторяющихся строк оптимизировать(сократить), если это возможно. Особенно интересно с onLoad & onResize ибо там очень много повторений. Острой необходимости в этом нет, исключительно для повышения собственной квалификации. Заранее спасибо!

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
var fixing_point=document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
$('.flash_window').css("top",fixing_point);
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
var fixing_point=document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
$('.flash_window').css("top",fixing_point);
});
$(window).on('load', function(){
var vw = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 if (vw<767){
    $(".icon_menu").css("display","none");
    $(".close-btn").css("display","none");
    $(".icon_menu_mobile").css("display","");
    $(".close-btn-mobile").css("display","");
 }
 else{
    $(".icon_menu").css("display","");
    $(".close-btn").css("display","");
    $(".icon_menu_mobile").css("display","none");
    $(".close-btn-mobile").css("display","none");
 };
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
var vw = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 if (vw<767){
    $(".icon_menu").css("display","none");
    $(".close-btn").css("display","none");
    $(".icon_menu_mobile").css("display","");
    $(".close-btn-mobile").css("display","");
 }
 else{
    $(".icon_menu").css("display","");
    $(".close-btn").css("display","");
    $(".icon_menu_mobile").css("display","none");
    $(".close-btn-mobile").css("display","none");
 };
});

  $(".icon_menu").on("click", function(){
    $('.flash_window').animate({
            left: '0'}, 400);
    $('.flash_window').css("right","");
    $('.icon_menu').css("display","none");

});
   $(".icon_menu_mobile").on("click", function(){
    $('.flash_window').animate({
            left: '0'}, 400);
    $('.flash_window').css("right","");   
});  

$(".close-btn").on("click", function(){
    $('.flash_window').css("left","");
        $('.flash_window').animate({
            right: '100%'}, 400);
    $('.icon_menu').css("display","block");    
});
$(".close-btn-mobile").on("click", function(){
    $('.flash_window').css("left","");
        $('.flash_window').animate({
            right: '100%'}, 400);    
});


$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var scroll = this.scrollY;
  var fixing_point=document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
  if (scroll > fixing_point){
    $('.flash_window').css({
      "position": "fixed",
      "top": "0"
    });
  } else {
    $('.flash_window').css({
      "position": "absolute",
      "top": fixing_point
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: очень много повторяющегося кода, можно вынести его в функцию

Comment: вместо обработчика scroll можно использовать css: [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: добавь пример разметки, к которой применяется данный скрипт

Comment: Да вот что-то sticky у меня не отрабатывал, наверное что-то с разметкой напартачил.

Comment: Поэтому добавка в вопрос примера разметки позволит более эффективно подойти к оптимизации: на данный момент кажется что все кроме click можно убрать добавив два класса в css, и по клику тоже никакой логики кроме toggle какого-то класса

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых, что бы оптимизировать этот код, лучше написать его без jQuery. 
Во-вторых, можно создать пару функций, например одна из них `toggle` и передавать туда аргумент `open` или `close` в зависимости от этого можно управлять данными кусками кода:

```
$(".icon_menu").css("display","нужное значение в зависимости от аргумента");
$(".close-btn").css("display","нужное значение в зависимости от аргумента");
$(".icon_menu_mobile").css("display","нужное значение в зависимости от аргумента");
$(".close-btn-mobile").css("display","нужное значение в зависимости от аргумента");
```

это один из примеров решения, дальше можно по аналогии